# Angular 4 with universal "Unexpected token import"

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

My project was running properly without universal but i am trying to use Universal and i am getting below error.

"ngx-page-scroll/src/ngx-page-scroll.service.js:1

(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Injectable, Optional, SkipSelf, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
"

My package.json

```
 {
  "name": "resumable-ang",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
  "prestart": "ng build --prod && ngc",
  "start": "ts-node src/server.ts"
 },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^4.*",
  "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
  "@ng-select/ng-select": "^0.15.2",
  "@ngrx/effects": "^4.0.5",
  "@ngrx/store": "^4.0.3",
  "@types/jquery": "^3.2.15",
  "angular-hammer": "^2.2.0",
  "angular-progress-http": "^1.0.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "ngx-carousel": "^1.3.5",
  "ngx-page-scroll": "^4.0.2",
  "ngx-progressbar": "^2.1.1",
  "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
  "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
  "devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.1.1",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
  "karma": "~1.7.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
  "tslint": "~5.3.2",
  "typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
```

}

Comment: My guess is that, since you're executing Typescript code directly with `ts-node src/server.ts`, Universal isn't happy with Typescript and can't execute it natively. Transpile your code to Javascript first.

Comment: @Jeremy Thille how can i do this . Can you explain in detail.

Comment: Well, Node and browsers are _javascript_ engines, not _typescript_ engines. Typescript isn't really supposed to be natively executed, it needs to be transpiled to Javascript first. I use TSC (TypeScript Compiler), others use Babel, to transpile .ts files to .js.

Answer (score 0):

Try whitelisting that module in your webpack config

```
//webpack.server.js

target: 'node',
externals: [nodeExternals({
 whitelist: [
   /^Nolanus\/ngx-page-scroll/
 ]
 })],
```

Comment: I have not user webpack.server.js, I am using only package.sjon

Comment: I am following this link
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)

Comment: any ideas? I tried to use prerender and removed webpack.